# Inverse of Cartan's lemma on closed subgroup

Tags: lie-groups

Does the inverse of Cartan's lemma on closed subgroup also hold? More precisely, if $G$ is a Lie group and $H$ a Lie subgroup that is also a regular submanifold of the underlying manifold of $G$, then should $H$ be closed in $G$ as a subspace?